# Extension file when called in not refreshing (swift3)

Tags: arrays, date, printing, swift3, extension-methods

I have code here that is printing out arrays. I have added a extension file to print out the time and date of each array entry. But the problem is that the extension file is not refreshing. So the date and time of the first array is the time and date that get printed on all of the arrays. I just want the date and time to match when the array is being printed.

[image]

[image]

```
    import UIKit
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var entry: UILabel!
    var arrayOfInt = [Int]()

       @IBOutlet var label: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func enterScore(_ sender: Any) {

    if let text = label.text {
        if let number = Int(text){
            arrayOfInt.insert(number, at: 0)

            entry.text = arrayOfInt.map { " \(Date.formattedNow) | \($0)" }.joined(separator:"\n\n")

            }}

        else {
        entry.text = "Please Enter Number"

        }}}

extension Date {
static var formattedNow: String = {
    let now = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "EST")
    return dateFormatter.string(from: now)
}()}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the creation time of each number in your array, you will need to use an array of tuples and modify the extension to be an instance method and work on self, not the current date.

```
var numbersWithCreationDates = [(Int,Date)]()
numbersWithCreationDates.append((2,Date()))
sleep(5)
numbersWithCreationDates.append((5,Date()))

extension Date {
    var estDate: String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "EST")
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}

for current in numbersWithCreationDates {
    print("Date: \(current.1.estDate), number: \(current.0)")
}
```

Above code prints

```
Date: 05/09/2017 09:51:46, number: 2
Date: 05/09/2017 09:51:51, number: 5
```

Sleep 5 is only needed for testing in Playground, you can omit that in your actual code.

Comment: I tried that. Error message states extensions may contain not stored properties.

Comment: Please show the exact error message, since this is a computed property, which extensions can indeed store.

Comment: I have added a picture in my question which includes the error message. All I did in this pic was remove the static from "static var formattedNow: String = {"

Comment: Tried it, but it did not work. I have updated my question with a pic of your answer. Still the same error message.

Comment: My bad, I missed the = sign in the declaration of formattedNow completely, that's what made this a stored property. Without that the compiler recognises formattedNow as a computed property and doesn't throw an error. I also changed the property back to being a type method, I realised it makes more sense for your use case.

Comment: This did work but now only the lasted time is being saved. For example if a was entered at 930 and b was enter at 935. B and A are both being displayed as entered at 935. How can I get the original times to be display?

Comment: This is what your original code tried to do as well and this is what you ask for in your last sentence.
If you want to show the creation date of your elements, you need to completely rethink your code. Instead of an array of Ints, you need to have an array of tuples, which contain the Int and a Date.

Comment: Anyways, I have updated my answer so that now you can see the creation date of the elements of the array.

Comment: Ok I will get to work thank you for pointing me in the right direction.